# Before and after works different after overflow: auto

Tags: css, overflow

I have a tooltip div, which has modified border on top to look like arrow, which is done by some before and after attributes. But when I use overflow: auto on that div, that "arrow" disappears.

How it should looks without `overflow:auto;`:
http://jsfiddle.net/nmvh4L6g/1/

How it looks with `overflow: auto;`:
http://jsfiddle.net/nmvh4L6g/2/

Sorry for my english and thanks for any help!

Comment: why u need overflow:auto;

Comment: Because its tooltip with notifications, and I need it to work like on Facebook. While there is more notifications than 500px height, I need scrollbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In top of my head, you can use an internal div, like:

```
<div id="tooltipNotifikace">
    <div>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

And in CSS, you use the overflow in the internal div:

```
#tooltipNotifikace > div {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmvh4L6g/7/

Comment: Yeah, I think this will work! Thanks very much for help!

Comment: I forgot to post the JSFiddle before :) .. Glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to set the `overflow-y` to `auto`. The tooltip will adjust its height automatically until it reaches the `max-height` value of `500px` you have set.

### Edit:

I guess I'm feeling magnanimous today:

```css
/* Based on http://css-tricks.com/bubble-point-tooltips-with-css3-jquery/ */
.tooltipWrap {
    position: fixed;
    right: 6px;
    top: 20px;
}
#tooltipNotifikace, .arrow:after {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #0dbe48;    
}
#tooltipNotifikace {
    color: #1bc204;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 350px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #0dbe48;
    z-index:1;
}

.arrow {
  width: 70px;
  height: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  top: -16px;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltipWrap"><div id="tooltipNotifikace">Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet.</div><div class="arrow"></div></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/kqm6jwjs/).

Comment: Uhmmm, in your fiddle, the content exceeds the max-height set to the container. Of course it will overflow! http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/nmvh4L6g/6/

Comment: Yeah, thats the reason why, I need that overflow: auto... Like I wrote before, I need that tooltip works like on FB